# BottomNavigation not work in fragment with component navigation

Tags: java, android, components

bottomnavigation not change fragment when i click, it work on activity but when i use it in fragment, it not.

my fragment

```
public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentMessageBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMessageBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);


        NavController navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(MessageFragment.this);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(binding.answerNavView22, navController);


        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```

in xml of fragment

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:backgroundTint="#E3E1E1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="2dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/layout_answer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:layout_below="@id/answer_nav_view22"
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_answer" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:background="#E3E1E1"
            android:id="@+id/answer_nav_view22"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_answer_nav" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

i checked id menu , it same with id in nav_answer. i dont know why, please help me!

**have a nice day, everyone!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mình thấy như bạn đang làm thì nó sẽ là fragment trong fragment (host sẽ là fragment cha và mỗi tab trong bottom nav sẽ là frag con). Navigation component đâu có support dạng này

Comment: 2 cái đó cũng giống bottom nav đó bạn. Có điều là thằng Navigation Component không hỗ trợ, cái đó mình phải làm bằng tay như thông thường.